# How to format string custom formatting in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, string

Custom string formatting in SQL Server 2008

```
DECLARE @a varchar(11)
SET @a='40010510120'
```

Result should be

```
|4|0|0|1|-|0|5|1|-|0|1|-|2|0|
```

or

```
4 0 0 1 - 0 5 1 - 0 1 - 2 0
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? loops? string manipulations?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Thanks for quick reply. I did not try loop, coz i am not good at loop, but I am searching is there any custom formatting in sql server where I can define my format.

Comment: SQL Server **2012** now has a `FORMAT` function, but that's a new feature in the 2012 release, not available in earlier versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a lot of concatenation but it will work fine if the string length is 11:

```
DECLARE @a varchar(11)
SET @a='40010510120'

SELECT '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 1, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 2, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 3, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 4, 1)
    + '|-'
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 5, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 6, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 7, 1)
    + '|-'
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 8, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 9, 1)
    + '|-'
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 10, 1)
    + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 11, 1)
    + '|'
```

You can turn it into a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CustomFormat(@a NVARCHAR(11))
RETURNS varchar(29)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 1, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 2, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 3, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 4, 1)
        + '|-'
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 5, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 6, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 7, 1)
        + '|-'
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 8, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 9, 1)
        + '|-'
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 10, 1)
        + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a, 11, 1)
        + '|'
END

SELECT dbo.CustomFormat('40010510120')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @a varchar(11)
SET @a='40010510120'

Declare @i as int
set @i=1
declare @output as varchar(29)
set @output=''
while @i<=LEN(@a)
begin

 if @i=5 or @i=8 or @i=10
    set @output= @output + '|-|' + SUBSTRING(@a,@i,1)
 else if @i=LEN(@a)
    set @output= @output + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a,@i,1) + '|'
 else
    set @output= @output + '|' + SUBSTRING(@a,@i,1)

set @i=@i+1
end
select @a
select @output
```